# C++ Hash Deprecation Warning

Tags: c++, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I am very new to C++ and programming in general and am currently working through Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practices using C++. I'm consistently receiving the error below

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  C2338   <hash_map> is
> deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>. You can
> define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that
> you have received this warning.

I understand that the header file std_lib_facilities.h using some sort of deprecated function, but is there a way to bypass this? It looks like it wants me to define "_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" but I'm unsure of how to do that. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: what compiler are you using ? it seems that you are not using GNU C++ compiler(g++)

Comment: Looks like a Visual Studio error. Put `_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` in your preprocessor definitions. This should be in the c/c++ section of your project settings.

Comment: Don't use `<hash_map>` and `<hash_set>`?

Comment: Note that Stroustrup provides an updated version of this file that fixes this with the new revision of said book which solves this problem. You can find it [here](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning isn't about "some function" - it's about the whole of `stdext`. And it's not just hand-wavy, to be discontinued *eventually*, deprecated:  it doesn't ship with 2015.

During the early 00's work was afoot to revise the C++ standard; different compiler vendors, Microsoft included, put proposals before the committee along with prototypes. So they could be tested and evaluated, Microsoft placed implementations of their proposed extensions in `stdext`.

Eventually the committee chose what they were going to incorporate in that revision and released a Technical Report ("TR1"). Anticipating completion before the end of 2009, this was referred to as "C++0x", and compiler vendors began implementing these features in the `tr1` namespace. Finally in 2011 the standard was finalized and we got "C++11" with all its bit and pieces back in `std` where they belong.

According to Microsoft's proposal, the container would be `std::hash_map`, but the C++ committee chose to use the term `unordered_map`. `std::map` is an ordered container, `stdext::hash_map`, despite the name, is not.

Microsoft's compiler has been the slowest at getting full C++11 support finished, and the standards committee has since finished a second variation (C++14) and is working on a third (C++17). Microsoft is just-about finishing C++11 in VS2015 and a big chunk of C++14, with a few significant exceptions that are apparently going to be a major problem for the VS compiler (esp constexpr and template variables).

1. **Visual Studio 2015 does not provide `stdext` - it's *gone*.** This is not one of those "well, it may eventually go away" cases.
2. `stdext` is specific to the Microsoft family of compilers, so writing code using `stdext::` anything is not portable: http://ideone.com/x8GsKY
3. The standardized version of the feature you're wanting is [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), you should use that. It's essentially the same thing.
4. There are unresolved bugs in `stdext::hash_map`.

If you really have to use `stdext::hash_map`, silence the warning by adding

```
#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
```

at the top of the `stdafx.h` I assume your project has, or in your header files before you `#include <stdext/...>`, or in the solution explorer:

- Right click on your project's entry in solution explorer,
- Select Properties,
- Select Configuration: `All Configurations`,
- Expand the `C/C++` tree entry,
- Select `Preprocessor`,
- The "Preprocessor Definitions" will probably say `<different options>`
- At the beginning of the "Preprocessor Definitions" entry add `_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1;` so it reads `_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1;<different options>`.
  (or whatever was there originally should follow the `;`)

Comment: @TerryYanko Since you liked it, you can accept the answer by kfsone.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the define prior to your including of the header generating the warning:

```
#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include <hash_map>
```

You can also add the symbol in `Proprocessor Definitions` of the project file.

[image]

The later looks prettier, but given your doing something against the suggestion of the tool makers, I'd go with the first method, so you don't forget that you might get burnt latter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you used old "std_lib_facilities.h" header (stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h).

New version of this header, working flawless for the "hello,world"-program in MSVS 2015, is available at
stroustrup.com/Programming/**PPP2code**/std_lib_facilities.h

Found it out when had had the same problem studying PPP.